# How to Create view dynamically MVC

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

How to create view Dynamically? I create button Dynamically But my issue is when ever Click dynamically create button I need to create show another page I successfully created dynamic button.i unable to create view.whenever click that dynamic button i need to create view page.Can any body help.

```
public ActionResult MyAction(int id = 0)
{

 }

  private Actionresult(int id)
 {

  }


  @foreach (var item in Model)
  {
    <div class="floated">

   <a href="@Url.Action("MyAction", "MyController", new { Id = item.Id })" 
   class="Estates_button">@item.EstateName</a>

  </div>
  }
```

Above code i create button dyamically.now i want to create view when dynamic button cick i want to create view page

Comment: Guys can you help me sort out the this issue?

Comment: I helped you with previous question, but you didn't vote, so I guess the people don't want to help you :)